# QCView in Xcode Not Showing Image Importer

Tags: xcode, quartz-composer

I have a composition that works as it should inside of Quartz Composer, but upon loading it into a QCView inside of Xcode fails to display the input information from importer patches (image importer and XML importer, to be specific) after building.

The composition functions correctly and responds to keyboard input but that's all. This is my first real try at using Quartz Composer so I'm at a loss as to where to look inside of Xcode. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Some extra, possible useless information. The composition works as a screensaver and runs in Quartz Composer Visualizer, but not in Quicktime. Quicktime just displays a glitchy image.